# How to stop dictation window when using speech recognition in .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've been attempting to create a voice dictation app in vb.net - but I'm afraid I haven't got past the first bit!

I have the issue (and I don't know if this is just a windows 10 thing and if it can even be disabled, I've had a look around and it appears to be an uncommon problem) that a dictation(?) window pops up whenever I open my application, and it doesn't let me do the recognition from just within my application.

[The window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebpqy.png)

It wont let me add the image.

Apologies if my question wasn't written well - I'm new to stackoverflow, and thanks in advance.